# Add itextsharp barcode image to PdfPCell

Tags: itext, cell, barcode

I'm trying generate barcodes from a text string and then PDF the results using iTextSharp.  Right now, I have the code below:

```
// Create a Document object
var pdfToCreate = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);

// Create a new PdfWrite object, writing the output to a MemoryStream
var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfToCreate, outputStream);
PdfContentByte cb = new PdfContentByte(pdfWriter);
// Open the Document for writing
pdfToCreate.Open();

PdfPTable BarCodeTable = new PdfPTable(3);
// Create barcode
Barcode128 code128          = new Barcode128();
code128.CodeType            = Barcode.CODE128_UCC;
code128.Code                = "00100370006756555316";
// Generate barcode image
iTextSharp.text.Image image128 = code128.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
// Add image to table cell
BarCodeTable.AddCell(image128);
// Add table to document
pdfToCreate.Add(BarCodeTable);

pdfToCreate.Close();
```

When I run this and try to open the PDF programmatically, I receive an error saying "The document has no pages."

However when I use:

```
 pdfToCreate.Add(image128);
```

(instead of adding to a table, I add it to a cell), the barcode shows up (though it's floating off the document).

I'd like to send the barcodes to a table so that I can format the document easier.  The final product will be 20-60 barcodes read from a database.  Any idea on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are telling the `PdfPTable` constructor to create a three column table but only providing one of the columns:

```
PdfPTable BarCodeTable = new PdfPTable(3);
```

iTextSharp by default ignores incomplete rows. You can either change the constructor to match your column count, add the extra cells or call `BarCodeTable.CompleteRow()` which will fill in the blanks using the default cell template.

Comment: This was it!  Thanks a lot, I was in too much of a hurry to see a barcode I guess.